# ngClass más de una clase por condición

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy poniendo una condición de que si un campo de una tabla está a 0 que me muestre una clase y si está a 1 me muestre otra clase.

El problema es que si está a 1 me muestra las dos clases que le tengo metidas, pero si está a 0 me muestra solamente la clase low-paciente

```
 [ngClass]="{
            'row low-paciente': fpacientes.baja == '0', 
            'row list-pacientes-events': fpacientes.baja == '1'}"
```

Comment: has probado con `ngIf`?

Comment: @NicolasOñate me tira error con el ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row" [ngClass]="{
            'low-paciente': fpacientes.baja == '0', 
            'list-pacientes-events': fpacientes.baja == '1'}">
```

Así fue como lo solucione